# jQuery modify my html after ajax(img inside a)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want create infinite scroll and get html from server with jQuery get. I receive right html part:

```
    <li>
    <dl>
        <dt>

            <a href=/product/1/>

                    <img src="/media/cache/14/9a/149a1ecabfd10c168495c70ab5ab6ddb.jpg" width="237" height="300" alt='Some text' />

            </a>
        </dt>
        <dd class="title">Some name</dd>
        <dd>Some text</dd>
        <dd class="price">

                <span class="old-price">&euro; 10.0</span>&euro; 8.0

        </dd>
    </dl>
</li>
```

Then I try append this text to ul with command:

```
$(data).appendTo(container);
```

But browser render next html:

```
<li>
    <dl>
        <dt>

            <a href="/product/1"></a>

                    <img src="/media/cache/14/9a/149a1ecabfd10c168495c70ab5ab6ddb.jpg" width="237" height="300" alt="Some text">


        </dt>
        <dd class="title">Some name</dd>
        <dd>Some text</dd>
        <dd class="price">

                <span class="old-price">€ 10.0</span>€ 8.0

        </dd>
    </dl>
</li>
```

As we see, img inside a turned into img after a. What kind of magic jQuery create?

Comment: Your opening <a> tag is closed - look at 4th line of your code. The problem is probably that you did not quote the url.

Comment: it's failry obvious that `container` is the `DT` but you need to show more code if you want help

Comment: @Evgeny could be dues to copy from console too. If you copy from Firebug won't get closing slash tags on input or images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a href=/product/1/>` is interpreted as `<a href="/product1"></a>`. Try quoting value of href.